# Select long list of parameters in Oracle using see

Tags: database, oracle

I have a long selection list to be used in select in clause in oracle db and it gives me an error stating

> SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored

Is there a better way to get this data ?

My query is something like this

```
select * from clicks where click_id in( ''comma seperated list '');
```

comma-seperatedlist is something like `('1','2','3','4'.....)`

Answer (score 2):

Split the list. E.g.,

```
select * from clicks
where click_id in ('1','2','3','4')
or click_id in ('5','6','7','8');
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your ''comma seperated list'' with a subquery:

```
select * from clicks where click_id in( SELECT click_id ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the comma-separated list with a SubSELECT statement.

```
WHERE click_id IN ( SELECT id FROM the_interesting_clicks WHERE ... )
```

[ORACLE] Maybe you want a `GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` for such cases: their contents are local to a transaction or a session (depending on how you declare the table). So: load that temporary table with a prepared `INSERT` statement that you invoke multiple times, and then use a subselect.

Comment: i dont have write privileges on the db

Comment: @TopCoder: How is the list of ids built? Could it be deferred to the database?

Comment: I got the data from DW and i am facing same constraint there

Answer (score 1):

This is an error with SQL*Plus, not SQL.  Just add a newline somewhere before character 2500.  Or execute the statement in a different environment, such as SQL Developer.

Similar to what @John Doyle suggested, although you don't need to use a separate condition:

```
select * from clicks
where click_id in ('1','2','3','4',
'5','6','7','8');
```